# passing int/var to a different module in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked through approx. 20 similar questions which I can't link all, but unfortunately have not been able to extrapolate the information to an solution to my problem:

How do I move an integer (or string) from module 33 sub process2 to another module 34 sub process3 so that after the integer/string is defined and numbered in process 2, I can simply use in module 34 sub process3 after the latter module is called at the end of module 33 sub process2?

More concrete, this is my code:

```
sub process2()
dim a as integer
dim b as integer
dim str as string
a = 10
b = 3
str = stringname

call process3(a, str) 'line x
end sub

sub process3()
dim c as integer
c = a * 2 +b
msgbox(c)
end sub
```

I have tried for line x:
call process3(a,b)

And defining the dim a.. and dim b.. outside/above sub process2

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer there but I think you might have a misconception about how the syntax for this works:

The key is that you are passing the value of a variable of a known type to the other sub, but *the variables are not the same; and they do not need the same name*. This allows your called subs to be more generalized - they can do the same routine with different variables depending on where they are called from. See an example below which expands on this concept.

```
sub process1()
    dim totalPies as integer
    dim totalCakes as integer
    dim str as string

    totalPies = 10
    totalCakes = 3
    str = "foo"

    call process3(totalPies, totalCakes, str)
    call process2 
end sub

sub process2()
    dim highCard as integer
    dim lowCard as integer
    dim str as string

    highCard = 10
    lowCard = 3
    strrrr = "bar"

    call process3(highCard, lowCard, strrrr)

end sub

sub process3(ByVal a as Integer, yVal b As Integer, ByVal str as String) 'adds 2 numbers and sends string to msgbox
    dim c as integer
    c = a * 2 + b
    b = 0
    msgbox(c&str)
end sub
```

See that in process1 vs process2, the arguments are passed as different items, but process3 converts the reference to those items into simply 'a' and 'b'. This is a very important distinction - it means that whatever you do to a & b within process3 will not change the initial variables passed to it. Note that where I set b = 0 in process3, this is just a pointless statement, because at the end of process3, variable b will cease to exist anyway.

If you want to have 'universal' variables, which multiple subs can change at will, you will need them to be Global Variables (look that up elsewhere for more information. In short, Global Variables are not 'erased' on completion of a given Sub, they are stored in memory while the workbook remains open).

Note also that I am specifying that the arguments "a", "b", and "str" are passed "ByVal". This means that I am not passing the original actual variable, I am passing the value of that variable across.

Answer (score -1):

It was, as expected a syntax problem, apparently if you want to pass variables from one sub in a certain module, you also need to tell excel to expect those variables, hence the successful result looked like:

```
sub process2()
dim a as integer
dim b as integer
dim str as string
a = 10
b = 3
str = stringname

call process3(a, str) 'line x
end sub

sub process3(a, str)
dim c as integer
c = a * 2 +b
msgbox(c)
end sub
```

Note, the reason the variables needed to be passed was because the code became too long for the 2nd time in 1 procedure, due to inefficient programming. Hope this helps a anyone in the future.

Comment: Unless the variables were global or public, how else would they get into process3()  ?

Comment: In the state I was in at the time, unaware of any such differences, between global, public, and non-global/non-public, I assumed, that the moment the variable was created somehwere inside the memory of the digital box, it would be extracted from that digital location when required.

As mentioned, appearently it was more convenient to create seperate fields where variables are contained in unless stated otherwise. Thank you for your help and interest.